# Problem bluetooth with Logitech t651 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, bluetooth, multi-touch, trackpad

I have a problem pairing a touchpad Logitech t651 by bluetooth, i've tested it in android nexus 7 tablet and windows and the touchpad works.

My first problem was that ubuntu 12.04 crashes when i use a usb bluetooth adapter, i installed blueman and reboot, now i have blueman-manager and ubuntu does not crash anymore when i use the bluetooth adapter.

Now my real problem is pairing and making works the touchpad, in the blueman-manager appears the Logitech t651 like a mouse/touchpad device, then i select the option to set up a new device, in the wizard i select the device, in type use input device, in pair password use '0000' then try to pair but the program fails, the device is added but not connected.

How can i connect the touchpad?

Is there anyway to force the connection?, i do not understand why in android and windows is to easy to connect it and in linux is really hard.

Is possible tha the last stable ubuntu version has fixed this problem? (in that case i'd upgrade)

how can i make the connection persisten?

Note: The touchpad is supposed to be desiged for mac (tested and works on mac), but i've tested on android 4.4, android 4.2 (multi touch works) and windows 7 (no gestures but pointer and two fingers scroll works), other people has tested it in windows 8 (works well).

Comment: Try this [workaround] for connecting the Apple Magic Trackpad. It seems it also has some issues connecting. It is worth a try. [workaround]: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/618838/comments/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've met a same problem, and solved using commandline tools.
Please refer [Bluetooth from the command line in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187092/bluetooth-from-the-command-line-in-12-04)

My successful steps here:

- Open a terminal.
- Get your bluetooth dongle device id by running: hciconfig

  For example, you can get hci0.
- Get T651's adress by running: hcitool scan
- Run following command:

  bluez-simple-agent [BT dongle id] [T651's address]
- Enter the pin code: 0000
- Now T651 is connected.
- Click BT icon on the menubar in desktop, and turn on the switch of T651.