# How to unpair bluetooth device from the command line

Tags: bluetooth

How do you unpair a bluetooth device from the command line?

I was able to pair my computer with an Android phone via `bluetoothctl`, but there doesn't seem to be any "unpair" option. Even though I removed the pairing on the phone, running `paired-devices` still lists it. I've tried running `disconnect` and `remove` but they say my device doesn't exist.

Comment: You should be able to [do this with `bluez-simple-agent`](http://askubuntu.com/a/187100/3940).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

first of all start your Bluetooth from System settings.

Open terminal and type:

```
bluetoothctl
```

then you should see the list of devices you have paired with and their corresponding MAC address. If you do not, type:

```
paired-devices
```

To un-pair a device type:

```
remove aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

replace `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff` with the MAC address of the device to un-pair.

*there is no un-pair commmand*

Comment: In case anybody is searching for blocking a device from reconnecting: use `block aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff`

Answer (score 6):

In case somebody looks for an up to date answer.
The interface of `bluetoothctl` has changed a bit. The following answer is valid for Ubuntuu 20.04 LTS:

To unpair, now do the following:
Open the bluetooth command line by entering

```
bluetoothctl
```

in the command line. After this you get a list of all paired bluetooth devices by entering `paired-devices`

```
[bluetooth]# paired-devices
Device F4:4E:FD:48:08:FF SoundCore mini
Device 30:C0:1B:79:6B:FF JBL GO 2
Device 7C:96:D2:88:2A:FF Soundcore Motion+
```

Now you can remove pairing of the desired devices with `remove mac:id` and control the result with executing `paired-

```
[bluetooth]# remove 7C:96:D2:88:2A:FF
[DEL] Device 7C:96:D2:88:2A:FF Soundcore Motion+
Device has been removed
[bluetooth]# paired-devices
Device F4:4E:FD:48:08:FF SoundCore mini
Device 30:C0:1B:79:6B:FF JBL GO 2
```

now you can leave the bluetooth command line by entering `exit`

Comment: Can you elaborate in what respect "interface of bluetoothctl has changed a bit" and how it impacts unpairing?
Without such explanation you answer looks like a late duplicate of the accepted one.

Comment: The original answer stated that calling `bluetoothctl` will lead to a list of paired devices.
At least in my version of `bluetoothctl` this was not the case: I needed to enter `paired-devices`  first after executing `bluetoothctl`

Comment: But I guess "editing" the original post would have been the better solution here, as indeed my answer is only a more verbose version of the original answer ...

Comment: It is now `devices Paired` to list paired devices.